# MySQL - Writing Command Joining Tables

Tags: mysql, join, union

I need some helping collating multiple data across different tables in the simplest way possible. I am not sure if I should be using JOIN or UNION.

Table 1 contains a column named "Passenger_ID" and another column "Trip_ID"

Table 2 contains a column named "Trip_ID" and "Trip_Locations"

Table 3 contains a column named "Trip_Locations" and "City"

There are other columns in these table but for now these are the main columns of interest.

Questions

I want to query the passenger ID and find out where the cities he has been to!

What is the correct MySQL query syntax for this? Is it best to use a JOIN or UNION?

Comment: Define 'best'! One will return the desired result. The other won't.

Comment: Anything that will do the job in this case is "BEST". I'm more interested in how these work at this stage to be honest :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query, i hope it helps you.

```
SELECT t3.CITY FROM T3 AS t3
   INNER JOIN T2 AS t2 on T3.TRIP_LOCATION = T2.TRIP_LOCATION
   INNER JOIN T1 AS t1 on T1.TRIP_ID = T2.TRIP_ID
   WHERE PASSENG_ID = "P1";
```

You can play with the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c9991c/1)